# use Guzzle wit name.com api

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

use Guzzle wit name.com api

that is the Curl example

```
curl -u 'username:token' 'https://api.dev.name.com/v4/domains:checkAvailability' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"domainNames":["example.org"]}'
```

php curl with Guzzle to do the previous request

```
$username='';
$token='';
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$url = $endpoint.'/v4/domains:checkAvailability';
$headers = ['Authorization' => "$username:$token",'Content-Type' => 'application/json'];
$data ='{"domainNames":["example.com"]}';
$data=json_decode($data,true);
$res = $client->post($url,['headers' => $headers ,'form_params' => $data  ]);
```

Questions :

1-Authorization is missing some thing like basic

2-name.com required --data as string but Guzzle required it as array

correct way to pass the data

thanks

Comment: I can't understand where did you stuck exactly.

Comment: You can use this webpage to convert the curl command into PHP/Guzzle: https://curlconverter.com/php-guzzle/

Comment: @jacob-mulquin , Nice help from Nice man